# summing up average infos with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to make a percentage of all my VMs who succeeded their backups but weekly but I'm pretty new with all of this and didn't got any courses or formations with PowerShell.

It's already working daily but what I want is to sum up everything and make a percentage of all the VMs that did their backups.

I wanted the script to start every 24 hours, make a weekly report and every 7 days, send a mail about the results. I already did the mail part but I don't know how to do the rest.

### Edit

I already did the average script for every day.

```
$success_rate = 100 - ($nbckp_vms * 100 / $total_vms)
```

But now that I have 7 days, I want to make this action 7 times, have the result saved each day in a .txt file and then, at the 7th day, make a success rate every week.
So, of course I know it's something like "all the results / number of results * 100" or something like that but, I can't actually make this work on my PowerShell script.

I have these informations with this part of the script:

```cs
# Check backup

$body = "*** VMs not backed up last night ***" + "`r`n" + "`r`n"
$total_vms = 0
$nbckp_vms = 0

foreach ($i in $csv1) {
    $total_vms++
    $VM = $i.VM
    $backup = $i.backup
    $today = Get-Date -Format "M/d/yyyy"
    $yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("M/d/yyyy")

    try {
        if ($backup -notlike "*$yesterday*" -and `
            $backup -notlike "*$today*" -and `
            $backup -notlike "No backup*" -and `
            $backup -notlike "TiNa backup*"
        ) {
            #Write-Output "$VM have not been backuped last night."
            $nbckp_vms++
            $body = $body + "$VM" + "`r`n"
        }
    } catch {
    }
}
```

What I want is to send to myself a weekly mail about the percentage of VMs that succeeded their backups. This is what a normal mail looks like:

```
*** VMs not backed up last night ***

Machine1
Machine2
Machine3
Machine4
Machine5
Machine6
Machine7
Machine8
Machine9
Machine10
Machine11
Machine12
Machine13
Machine14
Machine15
Machine16
Machine17
Machine18
Machine19
Machine20
Machine21
Machine22
Machine23
Machine24
Machine25
Machine26
Machine27
Machine28
Machine29
Machine30
Machine31
Machine32
Machine33
Machine34

*** Backup success rate for production KPIs ***

Daily success rate = 94.28%
Total VMs = 594
Daily unbacked up VMs = 34
```

The mail system works perfectly but I just want a weekly thing.

(I gave the VMs generic names)

This is what I tried so far:

```
$success_rate_weekly = 100 - (($text[1] += $text[2] += $text[3] += $text[4] += $text[5] += $text[6] += $text[7]) /= 7
```

```
get-content "E:\PS\Malik\valeurs.txt" | foreach { -split $_ | select -index 4 } | measure -sum
```

I found the last one on a french forum but none of these two lines worked for me.

Comment: Determine the number of VMs where the backup succeeded, divide by the total number of VMs, multiply with 100, and you have the percentage.

Comment: "I don't know how to do the rest." - please be a bit more specific about what you're asking, maybe check out the ["How to ask" page in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Like, I tried "get-content "E:\PS\Malik\valeurs.txt" | foreach { -split $_ | select -index 4 } | measure -sum"

Comment: And I tried other dumb things like ```#$success_rate_weekly = 100 - (($text[1] += $text[2] += $text[3] += $text[4] += $text[5] += $text[6] += $text[7]) /= 7``` but it doesn't work too...

Comment: Sorry for not being specific tho. First time on a forum ever :/

Comment: Hi @BasilGakali Could you update your question to be more specific. We need to know what you have already tried and what specific errors you are getting. Also, how are you getting the backup information?

Comment: There, I updated with probably everything I thought about. Tell me if you need anything else.

Comment: Why don't you use 2 scripts: one that runs daily and writes your daily report to a file, and the other that runs weekly and mails the reports from the past 7 days?

Comment: Could be an idea but the problem is still the same, I don't know how can I recover the informations from the .txt file on PowerShell, then send a mail weekly to myself about the average pencentage of VMs that succeeded to their backups.

I'm going to edit to put some information right now. ^w^

Comment: `Get-Content 'thefile.txt'`? Of course you must not replace existing files, so create them with unique names, e.g. by adding the current date to their name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*

Thanks to Ansgar Wiechers who gave me the idea of running two scripts, and to something really dumb I found on the internet, this is what I have:

First, I used Windows Task Scheduler to run my first script daily and recover my daily informations. I also used WTS to run my second script monthly who will make a percentage every month before erasing the content of the .txt file

I used this line:

```
$success_rate_weekly = get-content "E:\PS\Malik\valeurs.txt" | measure -average | select -expand average
```

And this line helped me to calculate the average of VMs that succeeded their backups.